# Java swing JTable inside JList

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, jlist

Okay so here is the question how can I put tables inside JList as rows. See screenshot. How can I achieve this?

[image: TimeTable]

Comment: In theory, yes, but I wouldn't.  `JList` isn't really meant to be editable, so you're going to have a lot of work to make that work.  You be better off formatting each of the cells so that it display the data for that given cell

Comment: Although rather old, you could have a look at [this](https://www.crionics.com/public/swing_examples/JTableExamples7.html) which demonstrates some interesting things you can do with `JTable`, this was done way back in Java 1.3 (I think), so there might be some issues getting it to work properly now

Comment: I would rather put the tables in a scroll pane.